# Find $\theta$ such that $W = X \cosθ +Y \sinθ \text{ and } Z = X \cosθ −Y \sinθ$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Find $\theta$ such that $W = X \cosθ +Y \sinθ \text{ and } Z = X \cosθ −Y \sinθ$ are independent. It is given that X and Y be jointly normal each with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

I have shown that
$$W \sim N(0, 1)$$
$$Z \sim N(0, 1)$$

Now, how can I proceed from here?

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ are jointly normal, then $(aX+bY,aX-bY)$ are normal, too, for any $a,b$ real. Now use fact, that if you have gaussian vector, then coordinatea are indwpendent iff are uncorellated. Calculate $Cov(aX+bY,aX-bY) $ and equal it to zero. You will have an equation for $a,b$. Set $a=cos(\theta),b=sin(\theta)$ and solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal distribution.

**Theorm:** Let $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be an n-dimensional RV with a normal distribution. Let
$Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_k, k\leq n,$ be linear functions of $X_j (j = 1,2,...,n)$. Then $(Y1,Y2,...,Yk)$ also has a multivariate normal distribution.

$W$ and $Z$ are also the linear combinations of X and Y. Hence we can use the above theorem.

$$\mathbb{E}[WZ] = 0$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2\cos^2\theta - Y^2\cos^2\theta] = 0$$
$$\tan^2\theta = {\mathbb{E}[X^2] \over \mathbb{E}[Y^2]}$$
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\bigg[\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2] \over \mathbb{E}[Y^2]}\bigg]$$